# Are Gem Squash Edible After the Green Rind Turns Yellow/Orange?

Tags: food-safety, storage

We've had these squash for a while.

I've cut them open and they appear to be OK, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, aging/ripening squash does not pose any food safety problems. You can eat all members of the family. You just have to make sure that they are only overripe and not rotten. Rotten squash will have areas which are much softer than the rest, and usually somewhat slimy.

It is a different matter if you want to eat overripe squash. Both the taste and texture will change, becoming mealy, or soft, or spongy, and the taste can get bland. You can try cooking it the same way as young squash. If this doesn't work, you can also try some recipe which masks the taste and texture change, for example something involving a puree or a coulis, and adds spices.

Comment: Thanks so much, that is what I thought... I just boiled them like usual and ate it out of the peel with some butter.

Comment: Keep them too long and they'll start to dry out and get stringy. With **Boiling!!!**, that might not be a problem.